# Does anyone know a way to interact with HP OV(NNM) with python, perl or bash?

Tags: monitoring, python, hp, perl, libraries

Do anyone know if there is out there any API/library to access NNM database from perl or python?

We have a NNM 7.53 which give us access to its data with its java based applet through http. And of course through the 'ovw' GUI interface.

I've tried to use Mechanize and selenium2(webdriver) to automatize some checks. The pourpose is to integrate it with our other monitoring services on our "general master console".

Many thanks.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

There are only three ways to Integrate with NNM 7.53:
a) Via registration files (no programming)
b) Via C++ API's
c) Java API's

All three are part of NNM SDK.

Any other mechanism is not supported. But if you find a way to connect via ODBC to the DB, then you can try anything.

Comment: Search for : HP OpenView Integration Series HP OpenView Windows Developer’s Guide. OR Manufacturing Part Number: T4979-90003
Document Release Date: May 2008 to get the document.

Comment: I can not find this document. Could you please tell me on which place is it?  thanks and sorry.

Comment: http://sysdoc.doors.ch/HP/J1261-90073.pdf This is a slightly older version of the document (but should fit the bill). If you actually want the integration, you need to get the NNM-7.53 SDK from HP, this would include the document I mentioned.